Does every uncountable model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ have an infinitely descending chain?
Let $\langle M, \in_M \rangle$ be a countable model of $\mathsf{ZFC}$. By Löwenheim-Skolem there is some elementary extension $\langle N, \in_N \rangle$ of our original model of, say, continuum cardinality.
As $|M| < |N|$, there must be at least one $n_1 \in N - M$. Could it be that all $n \in n_1$ are in $M$? If such were so, $n_1$ would be their union —hence belong to $M$. Thus, there is some $n_2 \in n_1$ in $N - M$.
Can we not extend this process and produce a chain $n_1 \ni n_2 \ni n_3 \ni \dots$ of $n_i \in N - M$?

It can be that there is an $n_1\in N - M$ such that $n_1\subseteq M$. For example, if $s$ is a subset of $\omega$ that is in $N$ but not in $M$ we still have that $s\subseteq \omega\subseteq M$. We have that the union of $s$ is $\omega$ which is in $M$ but this doesn't tell you anything as to whether $s$ is in $M$ or not.

"There is an uncountable well-founded model of ZFC" is generally thought of as true, I think (this gets into philosophy!). It is slightly stronger than "there is a countable well-founded model of ZFC", but still way way weaker than the very mildest large cardinal assumptions like "there is an inaccessible cardinal". So it would be very very surprising if anyone proved there was no well-founded uncountable model of ZFC.
